# On WordPress.org, how the downloads number works?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On WordPress.org how the downloads number works? After releasing the new version of the theme/plugin, if the user updates their theme/plugin, does it count as a new download?

Comment: Yes, in the updated also downloads are counted.

Comment: Hi. Please avoid edits that only change capitalization on old questions when you have less than 2000 reputation, as they are considered too minor edits for the review queue. Thank you.